# How to host Windows Server 32-bit on 64-bit hardware?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a Windows Server 2003 (32-bit) image and we would like to host it on a 64-bit machine. I tried restoring the image on the server but it didn't work (I assume it's because of different architectures but I don't know much about databases).

What are my options?

- Can I upgrade the Windows server to a 2003 64-bit version?
- Can I upgrade it to Windows Server 2008 64-bit version?
- Can I virtualize it and run it on a VM directly without upgrading?

These are all possible directions but I have no idea how much work is involved in each, or if it's even possible. Are there any resources you can point me to?

Comment: Go virtual. This is likely the easiest route.

Comment: Yes, P2V it. Ancient out of support OSes generally don't run well, or at all, on modern hardware.

Comment: `Can I upgrade the windows server to a 2003 64-bit version?` - No.  `Can I upgrade it to windows server 2008 64-bit version?` - No.  `Can I virtualize it and run it on a VM directly without upgrade?` - Probably.

Answer (score 2):

Step one is to mitigate the security risks, as [extended support for 2003 has ended](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2003).  Your options are:

- upgrade/migrate to a newer version of Windows and your application
- air gap it with zero Internet access
- get a Custom Support Agreement from Microsoft (quite expensive)

As everyone says in the comments, virtualize. The operating system of 15 years ago will not run today's hardware properly.

Talk to your reseller to confirm you have this hardware properly licensed for a vOSE, and any necessary downgrade keys. Copying the image does not transfer the license, you need to license the physical server.